# How to make 2 squares next to eachother one exists out of columns and rows

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, bootstrap-5

i want to make a website with a gallery block but i can't get it working. I only want to use Bootstrap with this and my custom css just for the finishing touches. So i want 2 squares next to eachother, left square needs to be 2 columns and 2 rows and the right square needs to be as big as the left square. Like the photo

I tried different approaches with flex box etc, i cant get it working as it should be

[Screenshot of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgSHr.png)

Comment: Show what you think is your best attempt, and explain what's wrong with the result, and someone can help you understand where you went wrong. Otherwise, there's not much choice but for someone to write the whole code for you from scratch, which isn't really what this site is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/assets/css/docs.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="p-3 m-0 border-0 bd-example bd-example-row">
    <!-- Example Code -->

    <div class="container text-center">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="col">Cell 1</div>
          <br />
          <div class="col">Cell 2</div>
        </div>

        <div class="col">
          <div class="col">Cell 3</div>
          <br />
          <div class="col">Cell 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- End Example Code -->
  </body>
</html>
```